# sddm won't let me login to Plasma

Tags: fedora, kde, login, sddm

I have the problem where sddm won't let me login to my box, it just throws me back to the password entry screen. When I change to a shell with Ctrl-Alt-F2 and login, it tells me `user change directory failed permission denied` with a reference to home dir `/home/user` but my home dir has the correct owner and `755` permissions. I can get to Plasma fine when I type `startx` from the cli. What might be going on, here?

This on my `Fedora38` box.
I have not tried another WM as I don't have another one installed and I'm using X11.

Comment: When you attempt to log in via the shell, does it actually log you in or do you get permission denied and returned to a log in prompt?

Comment: it let's me login & start plasma just fine

Comment: Got it, well the first thing you may want to try is checking if SELinux is causing you issues. You can run `setenforce 0` to change SELinux to permissive mode temporarily. If the log in from SDDM works, then you know it was SELinux and can look into how to apply a proper policy from that point. If that does not work then it may also be something to do with PAM. You may want to look at `/etc/security/access.conf` if you're using pam_access.so. I've had to add the line `+ : sddm : LOCAL` to my access.conf file in the past

Comment: @Natolio `# setenforce 0` seemed to do the trick, Thanks!

Comment: `setenforce 0` is just a runtime way to set SELinux into permissive mode. Permissive mode means that SELinux is running and logging everything, but not enforcing any policies. You're either going to want to set SELinux to permissive mode in `/etc/selinux/config` or the better option would be to look into fixing whatever context is preventing sddm/plasma from launching and/or creating a new policy that allows it. My first guess would be that the context on your home directory is not set properly.

Comment: @Natolio Thank you for this! I will spend some time this weekend to find out what caused this but set it to `permissive` in the config file for now! Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing, comment back with the root cause if you end up finding it!

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the mess was caused by syncing the complete home dir with Syncthing. I didn't actually end up finding out all the details but I removed syncthing which seemed to resolve the issue for me.